# "A line comment acts like a newline"

Tags: specifications, go

I'm reading the [Go language specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec). The section on comments states:

> Line comments start with the character sequence `//` and stop at the end of the line. A line comment acts like a newline.

What is the point of specifying that a line comment acts like a newline? Couldn't line comments simply act like empty strings?

Lines (except the last) end in a newline anyway, so any line (except the last) will act like two consecutive newlines. If the last line has a line comment, then it can also safely act like an empty string.

Comment: Might be related to the automatic insertion of `;` at the end of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some potential reasons:

- they consider the new line as part of the comment
- they don't want any ambiguity, especially that there is another kind of comment which is sometimes equivalent to a space and sometimes equivalent to a new line.

Comment: It can't be the first reason because then a line comment on the last line would not be a line comment.

Comment: @Justin, considering the Unix origin of Go designers and the fact that Unix definition of text file is light but requires the last line to be terminated by a new line (i.e. it is a terminator, not a separator; that constraint is also present in C BTW), I'd not be so sure.